# Cropping an HTML element

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is how it looks now, I want to remove the blue strip which is falling out of the image.
I have a circular image, created with img tag. I want a small banner over the image in the lower half of the cirle. I am getting stuck in cropping the overflowing span element from the image.

```css
.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #527e35;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #c8e1b7;
}
.flap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 0PX;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .4);
}
```

```html
    <div name="image" style="float:right; padding-right:50px;margin-bottom:100px;">
      <span class="flap">keyword </span>
      <img src="content/baby.jpg" alt="baby" class="image">
<span class="flap">keyword </span>
      <img src="content/baby.jpg" alt="baby" class="image">
<span class="flap">keyword </span>
      <img src="content/baby.jpg" alt="baby" class="image">    
    </div>
```

With this, I have achieved the circular image with a thin strip with some text on it. I want to remove the overflowing strip.
Any help or guidance  is highly appreciated.

Comment: paulie_D i have added the image link. See if you can find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you haven't used `overflow:hidden` on the wrapper and secondly, because you are using `name="image"` instead of `class="image"`.

Also, the wrapper needs to have `position:relative`.

```css
.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #527e35;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #c8e1b7;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.flap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .8);
  color:white
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <span class="flap">Our Man Phil</span>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="baby" class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: That phil! This is correct, I'd explain a little bit more about why you need to use position: relative in the parent..  if you do not specify that, the element will be positioned in relation to the body instead of its wrapper.

Comment: thank you so much. Actually i have 3 such images, now after making these changes, they are now placed on top of each other.

Comment: @pracheese you need a wrapper for each image and label, you could use something like:`<figure class="image"><img/><figcaption>caption</figcaption></figure><figure class="image"><img/><figcaption>caption</figcaption></figure><figure class="image"><img/><figcaption>caption</figcaption></figure>`